# android change one row of List<CLASS> cause of clear all

Tags: android

in my adapter i'm using List as `List<Contents> bookContent` after fill this variable i want to change one row of that by position, for example:

```
bookContent.get(0).setContent("CHANGE");
```

but this assignment cause of clear `bookContent` after set that to adapter

```
bookContent.get(0).setContent("CHANGE"); 
bookContentAdapter.setData(bookContent);
noteInformation = new NoteInformation();
```

adapter `setData()` :

```
public void setData(List<Contents> mContents) {
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(mContents);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

before `setData` size of `bookContent` is 200 and after `setData()` size of `bookContent` is 0

adapter constructor:

```
public ShowBookContentsAdapter(List<Contents> items, Context mContext, IonChangeBottomViewVisibility mOnChangeBottomViewVisibility, IonSelectedText mIonSelectedText) {
    list = items;
    context = mContext;
    ionChangeBottomViewvisibility = mOnChangeBottomViewVisibility;
    ionSelectedText = mIonSelectedText;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the constructor of your adapter? How do you pass that data the first time?

Comment: @mVck i added that

Comment: I posted an answer that should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may help you

```
Contents contents = bookContent.get(position);
contents.setContent("CHANGE");
bookContent.set(position, contents);
bookContentAdapter.setNotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

All objects are passed around by reference. So basically you're clearing your original list and then add the original list (which is now empty) again.

A solution is to create a new list when you changed an item in your list

```
bookContentAdapter.setData(new ArrayList<Contents>(bookContent));
```

Or edit a specified position with `set(int index, E element)` which is available in the `ArrayList` class.

Answer (score 1):

The list you clear and the one in your adapter are probably the same list (same reference).

You could create a new list in your constructor:

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(items);
```

Or any other solution as long as you make sure you don't clear the original list.